# How to read video from django db with opencv

Tags: python, django, opencv, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a basic app  using django rest api and opencv.
The app simply converts video to frame and saves to media.

I want to fetch the a video from db and apply the opencv script then save to media but I am getting an error

```
Exception Value:    
Argument 'index' is required to be an integer
```

**Model.py file**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
import cv2
import tempfile
import io
import os
from .utils import get_uploaded_video



class MyVideo(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=500)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now  =True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    videofile= models.FileField(upload_to='SmatCrow/', null=True, verbose_name="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ": " + str(self.videofile)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        vid = get_uploaded_video((self.videofile))
```

opencv  file **utils.py**

```
import cv2
import os
import io

def get_uploaded_video(video):
    cap= cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    i=1
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == False:
            break
        if i%10 == 0: 
            
            cv2.imwrite(('new_image'+str(i)+'.jpg'),frame)
        i+=1
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Query the video you want from db

```
import cv2
import os
import io
from models import MyVideo

def get_uploaded_video(video):
obj = MyVideo.objects.get(name=video) # AT THIS INSTANCE U HAVE UR REQUIRED VIDEO

cap= cv2.VideoCapture(obj.videofile)
i=1
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == False:
        break
    if i%10 == 0: 
        
        cv2.imwrite(('new_image'+str(i)+'.jpg'),frame)
    i+=1
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can open it using url of file

```
    cv2.videoCapture(absolute-url-of-file)
```